# one navigation bar on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website using HTML and I wanted to put one navigation bar on every page so I created a separate HTML for navigation but I don't know how to put it on every page. this is a small part of my navigation HTML code what do I have to do to put it on every page. and I am not meant to use PHP.

```
<body>
<div id="nav" class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Profile</a>

            <div class="sub-menu-1">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Daniel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Robel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Yohanes</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>


        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Interest</a>
        <div class="sub-menu-1">

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Daniel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Robel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Yohanes</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: are you using a template engine (ejs) for example?

Comment: Does this post help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31954089/how-can-i-reuse-a-navigation-bar-on-multiple-pages

Comment: This link should help you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54924877/6596443

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use iframe (tag of HTML)

which shows one HTML page's O/P on other else change only 2nd iframe's O/P

Take only navigation bar in first iframe and all other HTML pages in 2nd iframe