# Can't make <header> and <footer> shared across pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I tried to put <header> and <footer> in external files. In the console, the code outputs fine, but then the code returns undefined.

Footer HTML:

```
<footer id="footer" class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <a style="text-anchor: middle">© 2021 AlexInCube</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.html

```
<script>document.write(importHTMLdata("content/basement.html"))</script>
```

scripts.js

```
function importHTMLdata(path){
    $.get(path, function(html_string)
    {
        console.log(html_string)
        return html_string;
    });
```

Comment: document.write override existing texts so not good to use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54924823/16846346 try to take a reference from this

Comment: @Rana it's "ok" if it's used inline like here, it won't overwrite anything.  By "ok", I mean it works as expected, certainly not recommended.  However `$.get` is asynchronous, which is OPs problem, so there's nothing write at the time it tries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is NOT recommended to have document.write - it will wipe the page if executed after page load.

Just have this in your js file

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  const importHTMLdata = path => { // define a function taking a path
    $.get(path, function(html_string) { // get the path
      $("body")[path.indexOf("footer") != -1 ? "append" : "prepend"](html_string); // if footer call $("body").append, if not call $("body").prepend
    });
  }
  importHTMLdata("content/header.html"); // load header
  importHTMLdata("content/footer.html")  // load  footer
});
```

```html
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```