# How to include HTML in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, include

I want to include an HTML snippet in another HTML file. I am trying to do [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp), so I have the following files inside a directory:

```
include.js
include_this.html
main.html
```

with the following contents:

`main.html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Whatever</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Including</h1>
        <p>This was not included.</p>
        <div w3-include-html="include_this.html"></div>
        <script src="include.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`include_this.html`:

```html
<p>This was included</p>
```

`include.js`:

```js
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /* Loop through a collection of all HTML elements: */
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /* Make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name: */
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /* Remove the attribute, and call this function once more: */
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /* Exit the function: */
      return;
    }
  }
}

includeHTML();
```

Now, when I open this with any web browser all I see is this:

[image]

Why doesn't it work? How can I include the `include_this.html` snippet inside `main.html`?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the console?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  In the script debugger, when you place breakpoints and step through the code line by line as it executes, what specifically happens?  Which operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: I see there is an error, seems like the operation is not supported. But how can I include HTML? I have been trying tenths of proposed solutions from many sources, a lot from SO, and none of them works because of this or that. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Are you opening the file locally or running it from an actual web server?

Comment: I am opening it locally. And looking for a solution to work in this context.

Comment: Just FYI, the built in way of doing this is using IFrame. What you are doing here is kind of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @ControlAltDel an `iframe` will embed that HTML, but with a different CSS and so (sorry, I am no expert on this). I mean that it will be different from copy-pasting that HTML inside the main HTML, which is what I am looking to do. In C or C++ for example, you can `#include "whatever.h"` and literally it is like copy-pasting.

Comment: Maybe it would help for us to know what your goal is for including the html file? How many times will you be including it? How complicated is the included html? Would it be possible to include the same stylesheet in the included html?

Comment: I have several `.html` files, I want all of them to have the same navigation buttons, logo, and so on. One solution is copy pasting the code in all the files, but of course not the ideal solution. So I want to have all this in a single file that is somehow included/loaded in all the other HTML.

Comment: @user171780 "I mean that it will be different from copy-pasting that HTML inside the main HTML" You do know that script injection is JavaScript's #1 hacking vulnerability, right? If I was your CTO, I wouldn't allow this: Too risky and too difficult to maintain. "Find another away" is what I'd say... But good luck finding your solution!

Comment: @user171780: If the intent is to open the HTML file from the file system (and *not* from a web server) then that severely limits the capabilities.  At that point you can't effectively use AJAX (which was your attempt above), or server-side includes, or any server-side language designed for this purpose.  With that limitation you may just be looking at copying/pasting the relevant parts into the target files, or using an `<iframe>` as suggested above.  If you control all of the HTML in question, I don't see how CSS would be an issue.

Comment: @David not just the CSS, but also the `iframe` does not know the size of its contents, so I have to hardcode in the HTML with the iframe the size of whatever I include. Otherwise scrollbars show up, or it is cropped, etc.

Comment: @user171780: There may be other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54924823/328193) as well.  Sizes, scrollbars, etc. can often be addressed with some style tweaks and perhaps a little bit of JavaScript.  But that's entirely theoretical in your case since it's not what's in the question above.  Ultimately, if you're looking to have any measure of dynamic content for a website, hosting it as a website is an important step.  Just opening an HTML file from the file system "works" for basic things, but it's not the tool for the job.

Comment: Why bother foisting pages of gratuitous JavaScript upon the user just to inject a single paragraph?

Comment: If you don't plan on uploading to a server, you can still host locally by installing something like XAMPP.  That will allow you to easily run a web server locally on your machine and then you can use PHP,Python etc.. server side. Even though I have access to multiple servers, I still run XAMPP locally for basic testing of things.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works like it is supoused to.
Your problem might be

> "I have the following files inside a directory"

You are not serving your pages with a web server, so probably ajax wont work, if you see file:// on your address bar then it will not work.

I recomend you using some simple web server or http server to serve your files as a web site in some address like http://localhost:8080/main.html

You can verify this by using DevTools in Chrome or any Chromium based browser hitting F12, going to Network tab, and looking for the include_this.html line, you can see there the result of the fetching.
Also you can go and check the console for errors.

By the way, all the XmlHttp part could be smaller using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) like the following

```
fetch(file).then(response=>response.text()).then(responseText=>elmnt.innerHTML=responseText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have the HTML inside of your JS file. This will allow you to use a single JS file and embed the extra HTML as needed.

I'm using template literals to wrap the content that way I can easily use new lines in my HTML instead of having it on one line or other solutions for that problem.

```js
const dynamicContent = document.querySelector("#dynamicContent");

const newContent = `
  <p>NEW embedded content</p>
`;

dynamicContent.innerHTML = newContent;
```

```html
content in HTML
<div id="dynamicContent"></div>
```